# Identification of 24V driver component

Tags: identification

I can't figure out what manufacturer this even is. All I know is that the top side is all connected to 24V and the bottom is all connected in parallel to a bunch of the same chip.

Part says 4614 and BV9K3B on it.

I took a look but couldn't find the manufacturer here:

http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_identify_integrated_circuit_(chip)_manufacturers_by_their_logos/A-E

Any Insight?

[image: https://imgur.com/gAmdpub]

Comment: The manufacturer is Alpha & Omega Semiconductor. I haven't googled the part yet (no time right now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an [AO4614B dual MOSFET](http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AO4614B.pdf).

Comment: You got it, someone in the chat directed me to AO, just came to the same conclusion so we're great! :D